# Transform Excel Formula to SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I want to convert a formula from Excel to a query SQL: I want to find every line in a table that has a column B calculated with a formula in Excel.

table X has 2 columns: Column A and Column B
The formula to calculate Column B in Excel using Column A is like this :

Column B = `CONCATENER("FR";(TEXTE((MOD((12 + 3*MOD((Column A);97));97));"00"));TEXTE(Column A;"000000000")))`

So basically, the query in excel will be like this:

```
Select * from X where Column B = **Query SQL using the Excel Formula** (Column A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of complete answer, let me give you some hints:

- CONCATENER: see [Concatenation operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Concatenation-Operator.html#GUID-08C10738-706B-4290-B7CD-C279EBC90F7E)
- MOD: see [MOD function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MOD.html#GUID-E12A3928-2C50-45B0-B8C3-82432C751B8C)
- TEXTE: see [TO_CHAR function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-number.html#GUID-00DA076D-2468-41AB-A3AC-CC78DBA0D9CB)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :

```
column B  = ( 'FR'
  || TO_CHAR(mod(12 + 3 * mod(Column A, 97), 97))
  || TO_CHAR(Column A)
```

Comment: consider using explicit format in the TO_CHAR function, e.g. TO_CHAR(Column_A, 'fm000000000')